# FutureBuilder inside GridView.builder while retrieving an Image from memory freezes UI completely

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make an app that loads multiple images from metadata and puts them in a gridview.builder, on Windows. Having thousands of items, I tried using FutureBuilder to retrieve the image and put it there when it's loaded.

```
                    Container(
                      height: 725,
                      child: GridView.builder(
                          cacheExtent: 250,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                        controller: _scrollController,
                        itemCount: allmetadata.length,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            childAspectRatio: 0.8 ,
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 275,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 25),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int sindex) {
                          return
                          Container(
                            child:
                            MouseRegion(
                              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                              onEnter: (event){
                                //something
                              },
                              onExit: _incrementExit3,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  //something
                                },
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                        height: 250,
                                        width: 250,
                                        child:
                                        allmetadata[sindex].imageloaded ?
                                        Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                image: Image.memory(allmetadata[sindex].image).image,
                                              )
                                          ),
                                        ): FutureBuilder(
                                          future: imageretriever(allmetadata[sindex].path),
                                          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                return
                                                  Container(
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                          image: Image.memory(snapshot.data!).image,
                                                        )
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                              }
                                              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                                return Center(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '${snapshot.error} occurred',
                                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              } else{
                                                return Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    image: Image.memory(File("assets\\bg.png").readAsBytesSync()).image,
                                                  )
                                              ),
                                            );
                                              }
                                          },
                                        ),
                                  
                                    Container(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                     //something here                                    
                                   ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                            ),
                          );

                        },
                      )
```

Any solution to this? How can I make this unfreeze or be more efficient?

I tried solving it by:

- Loading every single image in the init, but the app takes way too long to load
- Putting the FutureBuilder so every image loads when it's on the screen, but it freezes the UI when scrolling.

I couldn't find a better solution. Tried using Isolates but they didn't seem to work

Comment: Is it possible that `Image.memory(File("assets\\bg.png").readAsBytesSync())` is the source of the freezing? Try getting rid of it and/or changing to [Image.asset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html).

Comment: Nope! initially it was just a ``` CircularProgressIndicator() ```, I changed it afterwards to another image just to see if the animation itself was the one freezing the app, but it wasn't.

Comment: I think the issue is `future: imageretriever(allmetadata[sindex].path),` trying to call api and rebuild item.

Comment: Any idea on how to make it better? @YeasinSheikh 
It's a function that returns the byte array of the image, nothing more, nothing less. It cannot be optimized more, maybe the FutureBuilder can, but I don't think it loads more than once. Do you think it rebuilds itself more than once in the process?

Comment: Give a Try with  [/cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

Comment: Use a family future provider from riverpod.  They can all fire off at once, and they can all cache and provide individual loading indications.